# Jquery: call p element in parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to select the p element in the following html

```
<div class="parent">
  <p>Stg</p>
</div>
```

in this JS

```
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {
    $(this.p).aFunction(){
  };
});
```

I can't find the correct selector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this:

[find():](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('p').func();
```

[children():](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(this).children('p').func();
```

[Selector in context:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

```
$('p', this).func();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find("p").someJQueryMethod();
});
```

Comment: You might want to add some commentary/explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('p').aFunction(){
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [children(](http://api.jquery.com/children/)):

```js
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {
    console.log($(this).children("p").text());
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Stg</p>
</div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcn7dL2z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use the selector

```
$('.parent p')
```